# Loopback. How to get all roles for one user?

Tags: javascript, node.js, express, loopbackjs, relationships

I'm creating a Loopback application and have created a custom user model, based on built-in User model.

```
{
  "name": "user",
  "base": "User",
  "idInjection": true,
  "properties": {
    "test": {
      "type": "string",
      "required": false
    }
  },
  "validations": [],
  "acls": [],
  "methods": []
}
```

Then in boot script I'm creating (if not exists) new user, new role and a roleMapping.

```
User.create(
{ username: 'admin', email: 'admin@mail.com', password: 'pass' }
, function (err, users) {
    if (err) throw err;

    console.log('Created user:', users);

    //create the admin role
    Role.create({
        name: 'admin'
    }, function (err, role) {
        if (err) throw err;

        //make user an admin
        role.principals.create({
            principalType: RoleMapping.USER,
            principalId: users.id
        }, function (err, principal) {
            if (err) throw err;
            console.log(principal);
        });
    });
});
```

Then in custom remote method I'm trying to get all roles for User, using user's id. [Loopbacks' documentation on this topic](https://loopback.io/doc/en/lb3/HasMany-relations.html) says that

> Once you define a “hasMany” relation, LoopBack adds a method with the relation name to the declaring model class’s prototype automatically. For example: Customer.prototype.orders(...).

And gives this example:

> customer.orders([filter],
>     function(err, orders) {
>     ...
>   });

But when I am trying to use `User.roles()` method, (const User = app.models.user;) I get the next error:

> TypeError: User.roles is not a function

But when I'm making a remote request `http://localhost:9000/api/users/5aab95a03e96b62718940bc4/roles`, I get the desired roleMappings array.

So, i would appreciate if someone could help get this data using js. I know I can probably just query the RoleMappings model, but I've wanted to do it the documentation-way.

Comment: Can you see the `http://localhost:9000/api/users/{id}/roles` in the api explorer?

Comment: @icecream_hobbit, yes. I also can get the info by making 2 queries: first to RoleMappings, then to Roles. The problem is with User.roles() approach, which should work according to docs

Comment: How did you define the relation from users to roles?

Comment: @icecream_hobbit, "relations": {
    "roles": {
      "type": "hasMany",
      "model": "Role",
      "foreignKey": "principalId",
      "through": "RoleMapping"
    }
  }

Answer (score 2):

Loopback documentation suggests to [extend the built-in user model](http://loopback.io/doc/en/lb3/Extending-built-in-models.html)
to add more properties and functionalities.

A good practice is creating a model `Member` that extends the built-in model `User`. In the new model declare the following relationship:

`"relations": {
    "roles": {
      "type": "hasMany",
      "model": "RoleMapping",
      "foreignKey": "principalId"
    }
}`

Now, you can get all the user roles:

```js
user.roles(function (err, roles) {
  // roles is an array of RoleMapping objects
})
```

where `user` is an instance of `Member`.

Comment: thank tou for your answer. But it didn't work. Although it did work if relations are declared like this: `"relations": {
    "roles": {
      "type": "hasMany",
      "model": "Role",
      "foreignKey": "principalId",
      "through": "RoleMapping"
    }
  }`

Answer (score 0):

This is an old question, but I faced the same issue and was able to solve it by having the relation Antonio Trapani suggested and accessing the roles like this:

```
const userInstance = await User.findById(userId);
const roles = await userInstance.roles.find();
```

Roles is not a function, it is an object. By the way this is using loopback 3.